# Prevent form from submitting if input value doesn't fall in a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prevent my form from submitting if the `input` value is less than `0.001`, or if it's greater than `200`.

Once the user inputs a value between `0.001` and `200`, the form should accept and complete submission.

The `input` `min` and `max` attributes don't stop the form from submitting. Is it possible to stop the form from submitting if it doesn't fall within those values?

Comment: Use `input`'s `min` and `max` attributes

Comment: *"Is there any way in HTML or JavaScript to solve my problem."* **Yes.**

Comment: Please read question properly before comments. min and max is not working and I tried already.

Comment: @SteveMethner The question has been read properly, and Andrew kindly gave you the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy JavaScript fix:

```
<form onsubmit="validate();">

</form>


function validate() {
 var value = document.getElementById('titleeee').value;
 var var1 = 0.001;
 if (value > 200 || value < var1) {
  return false; // keep form from submitting
 }



 return true;
}
```

Also, this may not work, since you said `min` and `max` don't work for you, but here's a pure HTML solution:

```
<input type="number" min="0.001" max="200">
```

Answer (score 1):

@AndrewLi gave you the correct solution. Specify your input like:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="0.001" max="200">
```

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // or return false;
    });
});
```